# VueJS v1 - Server Side Rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, serverside-javascript

I would like to ask if VueJS version 1 has a server side rendering and that can be read by google crawler/bots for SEO purposes. I have read that server side rendering will be available in V2 but I would like to ask if there's a way in VueJS V1.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe the DOM abstraction that is a major alteration in V2 is what makes server side "rendering" possible, so it's not likely.

Comment: [vue server](https://github.com/ngsru/vue-server) is the only one i could find. though I (like most devs ) would recommend using vue 2 for ssr. because ssr is hard enough by itself,  might as well use the official solution.

Comment: It is the official solution, in  fact it's a feature for Vue2